# GNU Make fail with foreach->eval->call

Tags: foreach, makefile, call, eval, gnu

So I am having trouble trying to condense a bunch of repeated lines in a makefile of the form:

```
dir := XXX  
include dir/Makefile  
VAR_1 += $(VAR2)    # where VAR2 and VAR4 are defined in the included makefile    
VAR_3 += $(VAR4)
```

To a form like:

```
dir:= XXX1 XXX2 XXX3 ...
$(foreach elements,$(dir),$(eval $(call function,$(elements))))

define function  
$(eval include $(1)/Makefile)  
$(eval VAR_1+=$$(VAR2))  
$(eval VAR_3+=$$(VAR4))  
endef
```

However I am getting errors in that it seems that the makefile cannot determine how to build the files. I am new to makefiles and I have tried many variations in the function, foreach, etc but nothing works. If I put everything back to every line spelled out explicitly everything builds fine. Is there something obvious I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

When you have macros in the Makefile for base syntax of defining or including things (NOT in dependencies or actions), those macros are expanded immediately as the makefile is read.  It makes sense really, as make needs to expand them in order to figure out what to read.  But because of that, the order of the rule definitions matter -- in particular, other macros that are defined later in the file won't be defined yet and will expand as empty.

In your example, this happens with `function` -- when make goes to execute the `foreach`, `function` is not yet defined as anything, so it ends up expanding to nothing.  Thus, you end up not including any of the sub-Makefiles you want.

Move the `$(foreach`... line AFTER the `define function`/`endef`

Also, you don't need the extra `eval` calls within function (though they probably won't hurt anything in this case, they might cause unexpected results if `VAR2` or `VAR4` expand to something with a `$` in it.)